# How to write new file using Bigarray.map_file

Tags: ocaml

I want to create a new file with Bigarray.map_file like this:

```
let file_write_ba path =
    try
        let fd = Unix.openfile path ~mode:[Unix.O_WRONLY;Unix.O_CREAT] in
        let ba = Bigarray.array1_of_genarray (Unix.map_file fd 
            ~pos:0L Bigarray.char Bigarray.c_layout true [|(-1)|])
        in
        Some ba
    with
    | _ -> Printf.printf "some error"; None

let write_chunk ~inba ~outba ~inpos ~outpos ~size =
    let sub_in = Bigarray.Array1.sub inba inpos size in
    let sub_out = Bigarray.Array1.sub outba outpos size in
    Bigarray.Array1.blit sub_in sub_out

let do_write databa =
    let outba = file_write_ba "some_temp_file" in
    write_chunk databa outba 0 0 (Bigarray.Array1.dim databa)
```

So it fails to create sub_out, but then I don't know how to solve this problem of extending bigarray on map_file.

Answer (score 1):

Three things to mentions:

1. mmap() will not change the file size. You create a file of size 0 so it always stays size 0 and nothing is written to the file. You would have to have to resize the file by writing data to it or calling fallocate (not sure ocaml has a mapping for that) prior to the mmap() call.
2. using mmap() to write a file is highly inefficient. When blitting the bigarary the first byte written to each page causes a page fault. The kernel then reads the corresponding block of data from the filesystem and retries the write. The write then changes the byte in the page. At some unspecified later time the kernel writes the page back to the file.
3. error handling is near impossible. Write errors on mmaped files will happen at some random later time and there is no way to catch them.

Comment: So, what do you propose to do then? What is the easiest way to save lets say 4Gb Bigarray to the new file?

Comment: Using the Bigarray write functions from extlinux.